# Two similar classes show different initialization errors

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, class, initialization

I found an error when I test some codes from Github.

```
class Profile {

 let text: String
 let date: String
 let id: String?


init?(data: NSDictionary?) {

    if let text = data?.valueForKeyPath(Test.Text) as? String {
        self.text = text
            if let date = data?.valueForKeyPath(Test.Created) as? String {
                self.date = date
                id  = data?.valueForKeyPath(Test.ID) as? String
            }
    }else{
        return nil
    }
}
struct Test {
    static let Text = "text"
    static let Created = "created"
    static let ID = "id"
  }
}
```

The line of `init?` shows the error "constants self.data used before being initialized."

And I create a similar class of it, like

```
class Context {
let words: String

init?(text:String?) {
    if let words = text {
        self.words = words

    }else{
        return nil
    }
  }
}
```

This time it shows " all stored properties of class instance must be initialized before returing nil from an initializer."

For the first one , there is a workaround that I can delete the `else` block and give each properties an empty value would fix the error. However it would have me change the properties mutable.
( I don't want it to be mutable)

And for the second example, I just insert `self.word = ""`before the line of `return nil` could also fix the error.

But I really wonder why these similar cases show the different errors and realize the logic of Swift, and how can I fix it correctly?

Thank you for helping me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

York initializers are incomplete and that's why you get the message. Swift is type save, which means that all non optional properties must be initialized before the class is returned. Even when the class returns a nil. secondly, you can't call self (which is the class itself) if you haven't initialized the class. However, that should not be a problem in your case, since you've defined a root class. For your first class, please, implement the code like this and it should work.

```
class Profile {

struct Test {
    static let Text = "text"
    static let Created = "created"
    static let ID = "id"
}

let text: String
let date: String
let id: String?

init?(data: NSDictionary?) {

    guard let tempText = data?.valueForKeyPath(Test.Text) as? String else {

        text = ""
        date = ""
        id = nil
        return nil
    }

    text = tempText
    if let tempDate = data?.valueForKeyPath(Test.Created) as? String {
        date = tempDate
        id = data?.valueForKeyPath(Test.ID) as? String
    } else {
        date = ""
        id = nil
    }

}
```

}

For the second class you need to do a similar thing, which means in the else statement give words a value and it should be okay.

Comment: Thank you very much, I figure it out!!  And I think have to learn more how to use initializer in Swift.

Comment: Hi Donny, initializing classes is a bit tricky in Swift, since Swift looks very easy but you still need to apply the standard objective oriented principles as in Objective-C. If you want to get some good lectures on Swift, see the Swift course in iTunes U from Plymouth University. They also have this lecture on classes and initialization. https://itunes.apple.com/nl/course/section-3-step-5-dismissing/id950659946?i=356885145&mt=2

Answer (score 1):

Try this version of the code.

Code 1:

```
    class Profile {

    var text: String = ""
    var date: String = ""
    var id: String? = ""


    init?(data: NSDictionary?) {

        if let text = data?.valueForKeyPath(Test.Text) as? String {
            self.text = text
            if let date = data?.valueForKeyPath(Test.Created) as? String {
                self.date = date
                id  = data?.valueForKeyPath(Test.ID) as? String
            }
        }else{
            return nil
        }
    }
    struct Test {
        static let Text = "text"
        static let Created = "created"
        static let ID = "id"
    }
}
```

Code 2:

```
   class Context {
    var words: String = ""

    init?(text:String?) {
        if let words = text {
            self.words = words
        } else {
            return nil
        }
    }
}
```